# F# anonymous functions, pipelining

Tags: lambda, f#, anonymous-function, pipelining

I am trying to understand lambda functions from the beginning of my f# course and still struggling to read and use them sometimes.

```
let wordCount = "aaa aaa".Split [| ' ' |]
wordCount.Length // 2
let letterCount = wordCount |> Array.sumBy (fun w -> w.Length)
```

How I understand the lines above : The first two are straightforward, the third one is one that i dont understand. Since the `wordCount` is an array of strings `[|"aaa"; "aaa"|]`, how does `Array.sumBy (fun w -> w.Length)`  know that an array is passed as an argument and `(fun w -> w.Length)` just works properly. Does sumBy just executes the anon function on every element of array? Is this the same on .map and other such methods?

And also small question, difference btw >> and |>?

Comment: This thing working because F# support currying. You may read about it on [FSharpForFunAndProfit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/). I found this site as amazing source of F# knowledge for newcomers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `|>` operator, used as `x |> f` takes two arguments `f` and `x`. It then passes `x` to `f` as an argument, i.e. calling `f x`.

This means that: `wordCount |> Array.sumBy (fun w -> w.Length)`
Is the same as: `Array.sumBy (fun w -> w.Length) wordCount`

Now, `Array.sumBy f input` is a function that applies `f` to all items from the input array `input` and sums the numbers returned for the individual elements.

So, if you have: `Array.sumBy (fun w -> w.Lenght) [| "aa"; "b" |]`
This is the same as `((fun w -> w.Lenght) "aa") + ((fun w -> w.Lenght) "b")`
Which is just: `"aa".Length + "b".Length` and that is `3`.

The function composition operator `f >> g` takes a function `f` and `g` and it produces a new function `(fun x -> g (f x))` that takes an input, passes it to `f` and then passes the result of that to `g`.